# php system() command that calls sqlplus causes php to hang

Tags: php, oracle, command-line-interface, sqlplus

I have a simple php script which calls a sqlplus sqlldr file and dumps data into a table in oracle. I have narrowed the issue down to what I believe is the cause of my php script from hanging... which is:
When I run from a php CLI the system command does not come back to php, rather it hangs in sqlplus land. When run from a browser the script performs as expected and I get to the final echo command that prints to the browser: *I am done running now*.

```
<?PHP
system('sqlplus username/password@tnsNameOfDatabase',$out);
echo $out;
system('exit',$out);
echo $out;
echo 'I am done running now';
```

running this script from a command line that has sqlplus loaded will properly connect to the database and my output from that connection looks like this:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Mar 8 15:37:34 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Mar 08 2017 15:37:18 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning and Oracle Label Security options
```

now... the problem is this causes my php program to hang and I can no longer get back to the php script. How do I exit the sqlplus CLI to get back to the php script running?

The typical exit command in SQLPLUS is simply 'exit' and I have tried that (as you can see above)... which when run manually results in the following:

```
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning and Oracle Label Security options
```

How do I back out of sqlplus and get back into the script that should be continuing? Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

Actual method that calls this sqlplus script and again - works perfectly fine when called from the browser, but when called from CLI it hangs right here in this method before it returns.

```
private function loadTempData($object) {
$this->getLog()->appendLogFile('Constructed Control File: '.$object->getTempData()->getQaveLoadControl()->getFullPathFileName());
$this->getLog()->appendLogFile('Result saved in: '.$object->getTempData()->getExportFile()->getFullPathFileName());
    $object->getInsertCommandFile()->appendContent('$ sqlldr '.$this->getPersistEnv()->getUserSlid().'/'.$this->getPersistEnv()->getPassword().'@'.$this->getPersistEnv()->getDatabase().' control='.$object->getTempData()->getQaveLoadControl()->getFullPathFileName().' log='.$object->getTempData()->getQaveLoadControl()->getFullPathFileName().'.log');
$this->getLog()->appendLogFile('Loading data to Temp Table');
    $command = 'sqlplus '.$this->getPersistEnv()->getUserSlid().'/'.$this->getPersistEnv()->getPassword().'@'.$this->getPersistEnv()->getDatabase().' @'.$object->insertCommandFile->getFullPathFileName();
$this->getLog()->appendLogFile($command);
    system($command,$output);
// this line does not make it into the log...
    $this->getLog()->appendLogFile($output);
// this method does not return when run from CLI
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to use a program that can run non-interactively. `system()` runs commands, so `system("exit");` is not going to do anything for you.

Comment: sqlplus has no problem running in non-interactive mode as far as I know. This script works perfectly fine if I'm not running php from the CLI (ie calling the script from the command line). When I call from the browser sqlplus opens runs my .ctl file to load data to a remote database table, then moves on through the php script logging output etc...

the problem it seems is that when I run the php script from the command line, I get different behavior.

Comment: Also I don't see it running a script or anything, just starting the program `sqlplus username/password@tnsNameOfDatabase`. Are you missing parameters?

Comment: For clarity sake I removed the script it runs. I will update this with the actual snippet of code...

Comment: I added the actual method that calls the system() command... There is a lot of logging happening here for debugging purposes. All of the constructed strings are getting constructed properly.

Comment: Well I think your main problem is that `$output` is not actually output. See my answer for details, which uses your test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should always escape dynamic output to a shell command. Second, `system()` will not return the output of a program, instead it will display it directly. The second parameter is populated with the return value from the program, typically a 0 in the case of successful execution. To collect the full output for use in a log file *and* get the return value, use `exec()`.

```
<?php
$credentials = escapeshellarg("username/password@tnsNameOfDatabase");
$scriptfile = escapeshellarg("@/my/sqlldr/file");
exec("sqlplus $credentials $scriptfile", $output, $return);
// $output contains every line of output from the program, as an array
// $return contains the numeric exit code from the program
echo 'I am done running now';
```

Finally, ensure you're instructing the program to exit with an actual "EXIT" statement in your SQL file, [as you discovered](https://serverfault.com/q/87035/114341)!

Comment: Fair enough on the escape characters - for now I'm hard coding the credentials and logging in just fine. I appreciate the lesson for that. However I have attempted the exec() the shell_exec() and the system(), all of which fail to run from the CLI.....................

Comment: I'm not familiar with the program you're trying to run; have you tried putting an actual "exit" in your SQL script?

Comment: Found this - http://serverfault.com/questions/87035/run-oracle-sql-script-and-exit-from-sqlplus-exe-via-command-prompt - and it works. So yes adding the exit command into the shell script is what answers this question - thanks for the second set of eyes Mike!